# Z Index a pseudoelement behind it's parent

Tags: css, z-index

I'm trying to z index an element behind it's parent but it isn't working.

Here's my pen:

http://codepen.io/Tiger0915/pen/OPXway

and my SCSS:

```
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  background: grey;
  margin: 100px auto;
  z-index: 5;

  &:after {
    content: ":after";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: -20px;
    right: -70px;
    background: lightgrey;
    z-index: 4;
  }

}
```

how do I get my :after to appear behind my parent div?

Comment: You won't be able to this way, because pseudo elements are by definition *inside of* their parent element, and you cannot put a child element behind a parent element with z-index. Think of `:before` and `:after` as being before and after the *content* of your element, not literally before and after the element itself.

Comment: Try to use `z-index: -1;` in :after.

Comment: Tried that, it shifted my `after` behind the other subnodes of my `div`, but not behind the `div` itself. See my answer.

Comment: Oh, also z-index in div must be removed: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogLMmV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Like ajp15243 said, I can't position a child element behind a parent element.

So I ended up creating 2 different pseudoelements, a `:before` and an `:after`, both of which appear behind the other children of my `div` (using negative z indexes), and I can put the `after` at a lower z index than the `before` to get the effect I wanted.

```
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto;
  z-index: 5;

  &:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: grey;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  &:after {
    content: ":after";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: -20px;
    right: -70px;
    background: lightgrey;
    z-index: -2;
  }

}
```

Here's the pen:

http://codepen.io/Tiger0915/pen/XJKBoq

Comment: clever solution