# Issue in css layout z-index property

Tags: html, css

I want my #club-box to be at the top then ::before box and then #club. i have tried this by z-index property. What is wrong with my code.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBzJBW
HTML

```
<div id="club">
    <div class="club-box"> </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#club {
    z-index: -10000;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 648px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}

.club-box { 
    z-index: 1000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px; 
    background: #768;
    position: relative;
}

.club-box::before {
  z-index: 10;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 106px;
    left: 17px;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 263px;
    height: 124px;
    background-color: black; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make a pseudo element appear behind it's parent.

Check out this related question:

[Z Index a pseudoelement behind it's parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27572213/z-index-a-pseudoelement-behind-its-parent/27572449#27572449)

Comment: I think @joe right. You can read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index maybe other looking to Stacking matter.